# Okta login with Django and PySAML2

Tags: django, saml, okta

I am trying to implement Okta login in our Python Django application. I am following tutorial on http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/pysaml2.html . I modified code for django. But on step where function parse_authn_request_response is called I get error "SignatureError: Failed to verify signature".

I am using: Windows, Django 1.8, PySAML2

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/g4ms9DUj

Comment: I haven't used PySAML2 directly, however, I have setup Okta SSO with a Django application using Python Social Auth.  Checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33813844/826102

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just created a django okta plugin named django-saml2-auth.
https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth
It works with okta perfectly. hope you enjoy.

Comment: Hi @Felix, is the plugin still maintained ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error on my Flask set up for Okta. This was on a Windows machine. The reason xmlsec is not able to verify the SSL certificate, and this is due to the xmlsec library on windows.
I just moved my entire setup on Linux(Vagrant) and it worked like a charm.

But as a workaround, you can set a boolean which fails when cert validation fails to true(hardcoding). This is a bad practice. I am not too worried as our code is on Linux and working just fine.